# Keyup function isn't changing input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a simple form that calculates a few fields and calculates the total price as unit cost * quantity. I am trying to use a keyup function to automatically change the unit price as the entered unit price changes, but when I change the price nothing happens.

HTML

```
 <!-- Div for quantity -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Div for unit price -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="unitPrice" name="unitPrice" placeholder="Unit Price" required>
                </div>
                <!-- div for cost -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost" required>
                </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#unitPrice").keyup(function () {
        var quantity = +$("#quantity").val();
        var price = +$("#unitPrice").val();
        $("#cost").val(quantity * unitPrice);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Did you check to make sure the handler is running?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm sorry Im new to HTML and JS, what is the hander?

Comment: The keyup event handler. Which is the function inside the `.keyup()` call.

Comment: @Konovoloff That wad a typo, meant handler. The event handler. The function you're giving `keyup`.

Comment: Do you mean += $("quantity ")

Comment: and you have to parse to integer

Comment: @mazenelzoor he's already doing the conversion to a number  with coercion by using "+".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Your variable name is

> **price**

NOT **unitPrice**

.Hope it helps!

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#unitPrice").keyup(function () {
            var quantity = +$("#quantity").val();
            var price = +$("#unitPrice").val();
            $("#cost").val(quantity * price);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required>
</div>
<!-- Div for unit price -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="unitPrice" name="unitPrice" placeholder="Unit Price" required>
</div>
<!-- div for cost -->
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="Cost" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, I realized I had a typo but it still didn't fix it, but your working example did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo.
Change

```
$("#cost").val(quantity * unitPrice);
```

to

```
$("#cost").val(quantity * price);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong variable name. Replace this line

```
$("#cost").val(quantity * unitPrice);
```

with

```
$("#cost").val(quantity * price);
```